# Flutter - Processing a video file into a series of frame in memory efficiently?

Tags: flutter, video-processing

I am trying to convert a video file into a series of frame in flutter.

Currently, I have tried with 2 flutter libraries:

- `export_video_frame: ^0.0.6`
- `video_thumbnail: ^0.4.3`

However, both libraries are taking a considerable amount of time to process the video file.

- Duration of video file: 5 seconds
- Time requires to process video file into frames: 2 - 5 minutes

**Is there a way to process a video file more efficiently to limit the conversion of a 5-second video file into series of frame in less than 10s processing time on Flutter app?**

Other methods I have tried include returning a list of `byteArray` or filepath, similar processing logic to video_thumbnail (Returning all frames instead of a single frame). But I am facing some issues while implementing it.

- For returning a list of `ByteArray`, the app throws `Out of Memory Error` when parsing `ByteArray` from Native Android back to Flutter. (The app cannot compromise on the image quality. Hence, I cannot compress the image into a smaller size.)
- As for returning a list of filepath, the app's UI freezes when it is writing frames into the phone directory. (The app cannot compromise on the UX as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl :

I believe this is more performance efficient if you want to decouple the entire video into frames :

videoPath : Path for the video,
get a local directory using path provider : applicationDirectory
fps : Total frame you want for the video

```
        var command =
        '-i $videoPath -r $fps -f image2 ${applicationDirectory}img-%03d.png';

    await FFmpegKit.execute(command).then((session) async {
      final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

      await session.getAllLogsAsString();

      if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
        _logger.info('Frame Export Success');
        var paths = <String>[];

        for (var a = 1; a < fps; a++) {
          if (a < 10) {
            paths.add('${applicationDirectory}img-00$a.png');
          } else if (a < 100) {
            paths.add('${applicationDirectory}img-0$a.png');
          } else {
            paths.add('${applicationDirectory}img-$a.png');
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**FFmpeg is jack of all trade but master of none.**

I would suggest if you have time then use mediacodec for android and AVFoundation for iOS. They are much faster and both memory and cpu efficient.On top of that, FFMpeg will increase the size of apk and ipa if you use the software throttling libraries.

Mediacodec : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec

AVFoundation :
https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/